How to validate text length in Yup schema while ignoring HTML tags?
I am working on a project where I use the react-quill package in the frontend for a rich text editor. The entered content includes HTML tags, and I need to validate its plain text length in the backend using a Yup schema.
The frontend allows access to the document object, making it easier to strip HTML tags using libraries or browser APIs. However, on the backend, I don't have access to the document object, so I need a solution that avoids using additional libraries to count only the plain text (ignoring HTML tags).
Here is the helper function I wrote to strip HTML tags and decode HTML entities:
  if (!html) return '';

  // Remove script and style tags first
  html = html
    .replace(/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, '')
    .replace(/<style[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/style>/gi, '');

  // Remove all remaining HTML tags
  const textWithoutTags = html.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '');

  // Decode HTML entities
  const decodedText = textWithoutTags
    .replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ')
    .replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
    .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
    .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
    .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
    .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");

  return decodedText.trim(); // Trim any leading/trailing spaces
}
Description: Yup.string().test(
  'max-length',
  'Description cannot exceed 1000 characters',
  function (value) {
    const plainText = stripHtmlTags(value || '');
    return plainText.length <= 1000;
  }
),

This works well for the backend, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to handle this without any third-party library.
